# Difference between "detailItem" and "_detailitem"

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

What is the difference and the use of the id between `detailItem` and `_detailItem`, I found that in Splitview controller template.

```
if (_detailItem != newDetailItem) {
    _detailItem = newDetailItem;

    // Update the view.
    [self configureView];
```

Comment: Ken, I'm sorry, but I can't figure out what any of your three questions mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean, but in most cases, in ObjC classes, an underscore prefix denotes an `ivar` which is either private or exposed by a property.

In this scenario `_detailItem` appears to be an instance variable, while `detailItem` could be the property through which it is accessed.

More info on properties in ObjC: http://www.cocoacast.com/?q=node/103